# how to map depth frame to color frame WITHOUT Kinect

Tags: c#, image-processing, kinect, color-depth

I am trying to map depth frame to color frame without kinect.
I previously acquired the images, using Kinect, and now, based on the depth image where i can clearly see the person body shape, i want to match both, color and depth image, without using kinect method MapDephtFrametoColorFrame (i can't apply this method without using Kinect).

How to do this?

I thought in acquiring the points of depth where they are 255 (thresholded) and then match the [x,y] points to color, but i don't have any results.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not exactly an answer to your questions, but if it is possible to capture this information and store it with your images while the kinect is still on that will probably be your cleanest solution.

Answer (score 0):

I previously found an article pointing out how to do that ([here's the link](http://burrus.name/index.php/Research/KinectCalibration))

Here's the pseudo code from the site (and all the parameters are on the website too):

```
P3D.x = (x_d - cx_d) * depth(x_d,y_d) / fx_d
P3D.y = (y_d - cy_d) * depth(x_d,y_d) / fy_d
P3D.z = depth(x_d,y_d)

P3D' = R.P3D + T
P2D_rgb.x = (P3D'.x * fx_rgb / P3D'.z) + cx_rgb
P2D_rgb.y = (P3D'.y * fy_rgb / P3D'.z) + cy_rgb
```

Just like you, I have been trying to map depth to rgb data, however after using this algorithm, I'm still stuck with some misalignments, where the color mapping seems to be shifted to other directions a bit, which varies from image to image in my dataset.

Hope that at least these could help you to the right direction.

Comment: John, I tried to do this in this way: with the final image misaligned, I used MATLAB to calculate the distances between the mask and the body throughout several frames. Then I calculated the mean values for x_direction and y_direction and shifted the mask in that proportion. The result in not that bad at all.. I even tried later to atenuate even more the x_direction in a proportion equal to the mean_x_value * (x_position / image width). Results were pretty good actually, but still not a effective way of doing this

Comment: Yeah, I have misalignments in my results too. I asked this on StackOverflow, it seems like there isn't any good answer yet.

Comment: What about relating the depth with the Kinect field of view?